# How can I isolate the initial target of a click, if the click event bubbles up to elements bound to the same click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a nested treeview menu, with 3 layers of nesting. Each list item (of each layer) is responsible for loading some new content onto the page when clicked:

```
$('li', '#navigation').click(function(event) { // this targets all three layers of nested menu items

    event.preventDefault(); // prevents click from making new server request

    var url = $("a", this).attr("href");

    loader.load(url);
});
```

The problem is, when you click a nested list item (one or two layers down), the "click" bubbles up through each list item above it, causing all three to run the specified event handler `loader.load()` method. In turn, clicking any nested list item loads the top-level list item's content.

So, when the event fires, I would like to check if what caused the event handler to execute was the originator of the click. Event.target (and anything that tells me about the current list item) will not work, as they tell me the currently firing item, rather than the originator.

Finally, event.stopPropogation() would not work, because it would stop propagation for all nested elements, as they are contained withing higher level elements.

Any ideas on how I can determine the originator of the click event?

UPDATE: Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kUR3r/

Comment: Maybe throw together a quick jsFiddle with the html included?

Comment: Just added one: http://jsfiddle.net/kUR3r/

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I understand your explanation for why event.stopPropagation(); wouldn't work. I think my answer below amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just bind to the anchor, not the `li`. Why would you bind to the `li` in the first place?

```
$('#navigation').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  // whatever else your code does
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kUR3r/3/

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why we're binding to the li. I'm working with someone else's code. This seems to work for the time being though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

return false; seems to do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/kUR3r/1/

```
    $('li', 'ul').click(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var url = $("a", this).attr("href");

        // loader.load(url);


        $('.target').text(url);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: @BryceJohnson `return false` is the same as `event.preventDefault()` __and__ `event.stopPropagation()`. (You don't need the first line if you are using `return false`)

Comment: I see... although right now, doing that in my full project is causing it to prevent UI events as well... I'll work on reproducing with an example.

Comment: @BryceJohnson see my answer; is there a reason you aren't just handling clicks on the anchors? You shouldn't have to manage event bubbling at all.

Comment: @Mathletics Responded on your answer

Answer (score -1):

I think it's something have to do with your selector?
$("a", this) will trigger all a tag. 
I might be wrong.